# How to throw error from RxJS map operator (angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to throw an error from my observable's **map** operator based on a condition. For instance if correct API data is not received. Please see the following code:

```
private userAuthenticate( email: string, password: string ) {
    return this.httpPost(`${this.baseApiUrl}/auth?format=json&provider=login`, {userName: email, password: password})
        .map( res => { 
            if ( res.bearerToken ) {
                return this.saveJwt(res.bearerToken); 
            } else {
                // THIS DOESN'T THROW ERROR --------------------
                return Observable.throw('Valid token not returned');
            }
        })
        .catch( err => Observable.throw(this.logError(err) )
        .finally( () => console.log("Authentication done.") );
}
```

Basically as you can see in the code, if the response (`res` object)  doesn't have `bearerToken` I want to throw out an error. So that in my subscription it goes into the 2nd parameter (`handleError`) mentioned below.

```
.subscribe(success, handleError)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What about `throw 'Valid token not returned';`?

Comment: Fails to compile

Comment: Exact error message please.

Comment: Oh sorry, it doesn't work with `return throw 'message here'` but does work without the `return` keyword. Let me check if its working correct logically.

Comment: The error text is not being received in the `subscribe` method and the `.finally()` in the stream also triggers. (However the execution is stopped which is a good thing)

Comment: what does `this.logError(err)` return?

Comment: nothing - its just a console.log at the moment which i will mature later on to some error logging mechanism later on.

Comment: This is why `subscribe()` doesn't receive anything. `this.logError(err)` should `return err;`. `subscribe(...)` receives what `Observable.throw(...)` emits. If the value it emits is `null`, then `subscribe(...)` will receive `null`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Sir You are a Genius ! :) Its passing the error message now. However the last '.finally' method is still running. Is that by design?

Comment: Sure, `finally` is supposed to run in every case (success or error). That's exactly what it's made for.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Just throw the error inside the `map()` operator. All callbacks in RxJS are wrapped with try-catch blocks so it'll be caught and then sent as an `error` notification.

This means you don't return anything and just throw the error:

```
map(res => { 
  if (res.bearerToken) {
    return this.saveJwt(res.bearerToken); 
  } else {
    throw new Error('Valid token not returned');
  }
})
```

The `throwError()` (former `Observable.throw()` in RxJS 5) is an Observable that just sends an `error` notification but `map()` doesn't care what you return. Even if you return an Observable from `map()` it'll be passed as `next` notification.

Last thing, you probably don't need to use `.catchError()` (former `catch()` in RxJS 5). If you need to perform any side effects when an error happens it's better to use `tap(null, err => console.log(err))` (former `do()` in RxJS 5) for example.

Jan 2019: Updated for RxJS 6

Comment: Thanks @martin - Yes your solution works. I actually had a problem inside my logError method as well which @GünterZöchbauer pointed out. I had to `return` the error object from it and now it works perfectly :) Thanks!

Comment: @martin: Could you please develop why we wouldn't want to you .catch() here?

Comment: @Bob Because the OP was using `catch()` only to log and rethrow the error, which unnecessary if you just want to perform a side-effect (logging the error) and it's easier to use just `do()`

Comment: Is this identical to `return throwError(new Error('Valid token not returned'));` ?

Comment: @Simon_Weaver no it's not. `return throwError()` returns an `Observable<never>`, this just interrupts the observable stream immediately, without returning at all.

Comment: Documentation for the `catch` to `catchError` change and the `throw` to `throwError` change can be found [here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/v6/migration)

Comment: one could use `throw new Error('Error');` and use `catchError(err => of(console.log('message:', err))),` [throwError doc](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html)

`:warning: Remember to return an observable from the catchError function!`

Answer (score 51):

If you feel like `throw new Error()` seems *un-observable-like* you can use `return throwError(...)` with `switchMap` instead of `map` (the difference being `switchMap` has to return a new observable instead of a raw value):

```
// this is the import needed for throwError()
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';


// RxJS 6+ syntax
this.httpPost.pipe(switchMap(res => { 
   if (res.bearerToken) {
      return of(this.saveJwt(res.bearerToken)); 
   } 
   else {
      return throwError('Valid token not returned');  // this is 
   }
});
```

or more concisely:

```
this.httpPost.pipe(switchMap(res => (res.bearerToken) ? 
                                    of(this.saveJwt(res.bearerToken)) : 
                                    throwError('Valid token not returned')
));
```

The behavior will be the same, it's just a different syntax.

You're literally saying 'switch' from the HTTP observable in the pipe to a different observable, which is either just 'wrapping' the output value, or a new 'error' observable.

Don't forget to put `of` or you'll get some confusing error messages.

Also the beauty of 'switchMap' is that you can return a whole new 'chain' of commands if you wanted to - for whatever logic needs to be done with `saveJwt`.

Comment: Once I started thinking of `switchMap` as an asynchronous `if` statement - things made a lot more sense :-)

Comment: If you encounter `Importing this module is blacklisted. Try importing a submodule instead. (import-blacklist)tslint(1)`, then use `import { throwError } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/throwError';`, instead.

Comment: A heads up that as of RxJS 8, `throwError(...)` where the parameter is a primitive (such as an error message) will be deprecated. Instead, pass an error factory function, i.e. `throwError(() => new Error(...))`.

Answer (score 8):

Even though this question is already answered, I'd like to share my own approach (even though its only slightly different from above).

I would decide what is returned separate from the mapping and vice versa. I'm not sure what operator is best for this so I'll use `tap`.

```
this.httpPost.pipe(
  tap(res => { 
    if (!res.bearerToken) {
      throw new Error('Valid token not returned');
    }
  }),
  map(res => this.saveJwt(res.bearerToken)),
);
```

Comment: the return value of `tap` is ignored. this code does different thing than it says

Comment: I’m still getting used to rxjs. Would using switchMap be better? Can somebody suggest a different operator or edit directly?

Comment: I think that suggested `throw new Error()` is the best option so far

Comment: I was first skeptical about this approach but rxjs documentation has similar example https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap#example-2

Answer (score -1):

Understand the difference of throwError() is not throw error
https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/throwerror-is-not-throw-error-ad6c76c53377

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)