# Angular 4: How to properly handle app level http error as Observable error?

Tags: angular, observable, throw

I use an HTTP API that returns app-level error thru a json where status == 'error'.

In my signUp service, I do that:

```
    return this.userService
        .create(user)
        .map(
            json => { 
                console.log(json);
                if (json.status=='error') {
                    console.log('error return throw');
                    return Observable.throw('Credentials mismatch or not existing');
                }

                const user = json.data as User;    
                return user;
            },
            err => { 
                console.log(err);
            }
        );
```

And in my singUp.component, I do that:

```
    onSubmit() {
        // blahblah

        this.si
        .signUp(this.credentials.emailAddress, this.credentials.password, this.credentials.zipCode)
        .subscribe(
        user => {
            console.log(user);
            console.log(`SignUpComponent.onSubmit() found user.userId ${user.userId}`);
            this.router.navigate(['signin']);
        },
        err => {
            this.errorMessage = `*** SignUpComponent: Error while signing up {err}`;
            console.error('*** SignUpComponent: Error while signing up', err);
            this.resume();
            //this.router.navigate(['signup']);
        });

        this.ngOnChanges();
    }
```

Unfortunately, when the service returns an error (with the Observable.throw()), the component doesn't trigger the err closure but the user closure passing the Observable.throw as the user parameter.

I wish I had the err closure to be triggered.

What Im missing there?

Update: Here is what I get:

```
[Log] SigninService.signUp, zipCode=
[Log] {data: null, status: "error", message: "Error user create: - missing id   API usage v1b3: Tu…ate\"}↵post: []↵.↵", ws: "v1b3: Tuesday, August 25th 2017 20h20 @ Tanger"}
[Log] error return throw
[Log] ErrorObservable {_isScalar: false, error: "Credentials mismatch or not existing", scheduler: undefined, _subscribe: function, …}
[Log] SignUpComponent.onSubmit() found user.userId undefined
```

Comment: what is your `.map()` doing?

Comment: it looks for the API status in order to make sure the API returns the brand new user (when status=='success'). In case status equals 'error' (stands for user account is not created), I wish I 'to generate an error for the subscriber.

Comment: is this working?

Comment: I added the logs in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are handling the exception inside the user call back, it means it was succesfuly executed, in that case `Observable.throws` won't really act as an exception. In order to achieve that, you must use `throw new Error("Credentials mismatch or not existing")` that must replace `return Observable.throw("Credentials mismatch or not existing")`; Please, look at this: [How to throw error from RxJS map operator (angular)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43199642/how-to-throw-error-from-rxjs-map-operator-angular)

Comment: Thanks @dag to put me on track. Modify your answer to be: throw new Error("Credentials mismatch or not existing"); that must replace return Observable.thow("Credentials mismatch or not existing"); so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid the problem you are having, I think you just need to do `throw 'Credentials mismatch or not existing'` without the **return** and **Observable** parts. Any errors raised during the execution of an observable would be propagated as errors on the current `Observable`.

At the moment, you are just replacing the json response with an `Observable` which is not what you want.

Ideally, the server should return an error response rather than a json with an error message and that would trigger your `error` handler in the subscribe.

Comment: Nope, that was my first try before trying return Observable.throw() in a desesparate move.

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with the following solution, expanding on the fact that 1) with throw new Error() I can still return an Observable and 2) when error throws the subscribe completion parameter does not trigger, one need to use the finally() call as follows:

signUp service:

```
create(user: User): Observable<User> {
    const wsUrl = `${this.wsApi}m=create&id=${user.id}`;  // URL to web api

    return this.http.post(wsUrl, JSON.stringify(user),  { headers: this.headers })
    .retry(3)
    .map(res => {
        const json = res.json() as any;

        if (json.status=='error') throw new Error(json.message);

        return json.data as User;
    });
}
```

signUp component:

```
    onSubmit() {
        // blahblah

        this.progressing = true;

        this.si
        .signUp(this.credentials.emailAddress, this.credentials.password, this.credentials.zipCode)
        .finally(() => setTimeout(() => this.progressing = false, 1000))
        .subscribe(
            user => this.router.navigate(['signin']),
            err => this.errorMessage = err
        );

        this.ngOnChanges();
    }
```