# How to throwError within map of observable (rxjs6, ng6)

Tags: error-handling, observable, angular6, rxjs6

my question is similar to this one [How to throw error from RxJS map operator (angular)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43199642/10290557), but I'm on angular6 with rxjs6 and I guess all is changed ;)

I want to know, how I could propagate an Error-Object within map of an observable to the subscribe OnError Part. I always end up in the OnNext Part.

Here is what I have so far:

Within a ng-component I have maybe the following method call

```
[...]
this.dataStreamService.execCall({ method : 'order_list',params : {}})
   .subscribe( r => {
        // here r provides the result data from http call
        console.log("execCall result", r);
    }, err => {    
        // HERE the "MAP ERROR OCCURED" Error should be occured as well,
        // but in doesn't
        console.log("execCall error",err);

    });
[...]
```

The called service method looks like:

```
execCall(dataStreamCall: DataStreamCall): Observable<DataStreamResult> {

    let apiURL = '<some API-URL>';
    let params = dataStreamCall.params;

    // do HTTP request (this.http calls an extra service handler which wraps
    // the angular httpClient and the API errors there
    // There is NO Problem with that part :)
    let apiResult = this.http.post(apiURL, params);

    // Build a new Observable from type "DataStreamResult"
    let dsr : Observable<DataStreamResult> = apiResult
        .pipe(
            map( httpresult => {

                if (httpresult['status'] == false){
                   // the http call was basically successful,
                   // but state in data is false

                   // *** THIS IS NOT PROPAGATE TO SUBSCRIBE OnERROR *** 
                   throwError({'msg' : 'MAP ERROR OCCURED'});

                   // also tried as alternative
                   return throwError({'msg' : 'MAP ERROR OCCURED'});

                } else {

                    // here the http call was successful
                    let d = new DataStreamResult();
                    d.result = httpresult;
                    return d;
                }
            }),
            catchError( err => {
              // error is bubble up from http request handler
              return throwError(err);
            })
        );

    return dsr;
}
```

Finally the Question:
How could manage, that the "throwError" within the piped "map" is propagated to subscribe "err => { ... }".

The actual behavior for:

```
throwError({..})
```

I ended up in the subscribe OnNext Part with `r = undefined`

If I use:

```
return throwError({..})
```

I also ended up in the subscribe OnNext Part where `r` is the throwError-Observable

Thx in Advance
Best Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`throwError({'msg' : 'MAP ERROR OCCURED'})` will return an observable that, when subscribed to, will effect an `error` notification. That is, it will call the subscriber's `error` method.

In your snippet, you either call `throwError` and ignore the value. Or you return its return value from a project function passed to the `map` operator.

Neither will effect an error.

There is no subscriber in the first situation, because the return value is ignored. And, in the second situation, there is no subscriber because the `map` operator doesn't subscribe to what it receives from the project function - the `map` operator's project function can return anything; it doesn't have to return an observable.

To throw an error within `map`, use:

```
throw {'msg' : 'MAP ERROR OCCURED'};
```

Comment: Thanks @cartant you made my day. now I understand this things better and the `throw` statement just do what I want :)