# Exception in observable pipe is suppressed

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Suppose I want observable to emit value periodically until another observable emits. So I can use `timer` and `takeUntil` to achive that.
But then I want to process every emitted value and stop (error) emitting when some condition becomes true. So I write next piece of code:

```js
const { timer, Subject } = 'rxjs';
const { takeUntil, map } = 'rxjs/operators';

const s = new Subject();
let count = 0;
function processItem(item) {
  count++;
  return count < 3;
}

const value = "MyValue";

timer(0, 1000).pipe(
      takeUntil(s),
      map(() => {
        if (processItem(value)) {
          console.log(`Processing done`);
          return value;
        } else {
          s.next(true);
          s.complete();
          console.error(`Processing error`);
          throw new Error(`Stop pipe`);
        }
      }),
    )
```

[Playground](https://rxviz.com/v/7JXZKygo)

But instead of getting error I have my Observable completed. 
Only if I comment out `takeUntil(s)` operator, I get error.
Looks like when pipe operator completes, it's value is not emitted immediately, but remembered and emitted at the end of next "iteration" of the pipe, then replaced by new result and so on. And in my situation next iteration, when error should be emitted, is prevented by `takeUntil`. Question is am I right with that assumption, and if so, why rxjs is designed in that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, each Rx chain can emit one `error` or one `complete` notification but never both. (See http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html section *"The Contract Governing Notifications"*).

`takeUntil` operator emits `complete` when it's notification Observable (`s` in your case) emits any `next` notification. This means that when `s` emits the chain will be completed and you never receive any further `error` notifications.

The last thing and probably most confusing is that everything in RxJS happens synchronously unless you work with time (eg. `delay` operator) or you specifically use `observeOn` operator with an asynchronous scheduler. So when you call `s.next(true)` inside `map` this `next` notification is immediately propagated to `takeUntil` which completes the chain and as I mentioned above, you can receive one `error` or one `complete` notification but never both.

It looks like you don't even need to be using `takeUntil` because if you throw an error inside `map` it's automatically wrapped and sent further as an `error` notification ([How to throw error from RxJS map operator (angular)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43199642/how-to-throw-error-from-rxjs-map-operator-angular/43199958#43199958)) and the chain is disposed automatically so there's no point in trying to complete it after that with `takeUntil`.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, that sentence "The last thing and probably most confusing is that everything in RxJS happens synchronously unless you work with time" clarifies a lot. About `s`, it exists as in real problem it is used to stop pipe from outside, and I cannot just skip `s.next` in `map`, because I need to notify other side that processing is completed/errored

Comment: Then maybe you can call `s.next(true)` form an error handler in subscribtion or add `tap` with and error handler?

Comment: >add tap with and error handler
Thank you, I'll try that